# How to add ID of one class to another using Python?

Tags: python, logic

I want to add id of one class to another class, like:

```
(subclass A B) 

1,B (B has the auto increment id )
2,A,1 (because A is the subclass of B , so class A get the id of class B)
```

The output should be like this:

```
   1,B 
   2,A,1
```

But I could not add the ID of class 'A'. So is there any way?
My code looks as follows:

```
with open('aclass.txt', 'r') as in_file:
id = 1
id1 = 0

for line in in_file:
    line = line.replace("(", "")
    text = line.replace(")", "")
    line = (text.split())

    with open('a.csv', 'r+') as out_file:
            line_found = any(line[2] in l for l in out_file)
            if not line_found:
                output = "%d,%s\n" % (id, line[2])
                out_file.write(output)

            line_found = any(line[1] in l for l in out_file)
            if not line_found:
                id1 = id
                id = id + 1
                output = "%d,%s,%d\n" % (id, line[1], id1)
                out_file.write(output)
```

In this code first I replace () from line. then find the position of 'B' and give the auto increment ID. And then find the position of class 'A'. What I want to know is how does class 'A' get its ID from class 'B? As 'A' is a subclass of class 'B'.

Comment: It is unclear to me: i) How classes A and B look like, ii) How your auto-increment is implemented, iii) What the behavior is you are seeing and what the behavior is you are expecting.